# After Installing "Searchanise_SearchAutocomplete" Product Not Found in magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, product, admin, catalog, magento2.4.2

i install "Searchanise_SearchAutocomplete" extension in my magento 2.4.2 setup after i install this extention the search autocomplete not working.
and got only this error on catalogue product list page

> "We can't find products matching the selection."

[image]

in my setup elastic search work proper and re-index also run proper.

Answer (score 0):

sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush